# Add column of checkboxes in final row of table read in from postgresql db

Tags: php, html, postgresql, checkbox, html-table

I have a table that is read in from a postgresql database. I am having trouble adding checkboxes to a final row in the table so that I can then, using an add to basket function pass items to a basket.php file.

Firstly I need to add a checkbox to a final column on each row so that I can check against the items I want to add when I click add to cart. I am struggling massively with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated as my code is below. If you could explain what needs to be done that'd be awesome as I can learn from it.

```
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>ref</th>
    <th>title</th>
    <th>platform</th>
    <th>description</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>select</th>
    </tr>

<?php $resource = pg_query ($connect, "select refnumber,title,platform,description,price from csgames");
        while ($a = pg_fetch_array ($resource)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            for ($j = 0; $j < pg_num_fields ($resource); $j++) {
                echo "<td>".$a[$j] ."</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }


    ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
while ($a = pg_fetch_array ($resource)) {
   echo "<tr>";
   for ($j = 0; $j < pg_num_fields ($resource); $j++) {
      echo "<td>".$a[$j] ."</td>";
   }
   echo '<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="'.$id.'" />'; //replace with item id
   echo "</tr>";
}
```

Submitting the form will populate the `items[]` variable

```
$items = $_POST['items']; //array of itemid selected

output
---------
var_dump(items) = Array ( [items] => Array ( [0] => item123 [1] => item125 ) )
```